# React Native - React Navigation Drawer Bug

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have discovered a bug with the **createDrawerNavigator** nested inside a **createBottomTabNavigator**. I have set up an expo project so you can test it for yourself: https://snack.expo.io/Hy299PSRN
.The Bug can be described as followed: 
 When you are using the build in gestures to open and close the drawer by swiping left and right on the screen, especially if you don't fully open it and then switch to another Tab, Screen 2 or 3 in my example, the app immediately switches back to the drawer screen.
In my case I have used 2 drawers on the same screen but this can also be replicated with only on Drawer. Here is the navigation setup:

```
const RightDrawer = createDrawerNavigator(
  { Screen1 },
  {
    contentComponent: Drawer2,
    drawerPosition: 'right',
    drawerWidth: SCREEN_WIDTH - 50,
    edgeWidth: SCREEN_WIDTH * 0.5,
    getCustomActionCreators: (route, stateKey) => ({
      openBottomLevelDrawer: () => DrawerActions.openDrawer({ key: stateKey }),
    }),
  }
);

const LeftDrawer = createDrawerNavigator(
  { RightDrawer },
  {
    contentComponent: Drawer1,
    drawerWidth: SCREEN_WIDTH - 50,
    edgeWidth: SCREEN_WIDTH * 0.5,
    getCustomActionCreators: (route, stateKey) => ({
      openTopLevelDrawer: () => DrawerActions.openDrawer({ key: stateKey }),
    }),
  }
);

const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
  Screen1: { screen: RightDrawer },
  Screen2,
  Screen3,
});

const Navigator = createAppContainer(TabNavigator);
```

You can see all the code on expo.
Does anybody know how to solve this?

Thank you

[image: Bug]

Comment: Why are you using a nested drawers? I think this may be more of UI issue rather than a bug.

Comment: I just wandet to have two drawers on the same screen one on the left side and one on the right, but this wasn't the issue, this bug got resolved with the 2.0.0-alpha.2 release of react-navigation-drawer